# Django Rest Framework how assign values manually (without data) for relational fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
class Listing(...):
   ...

class ListingImage(...):
   listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
   ...
```

and a serializer field for listing images:

```
class ListingImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ListingImage
        fields = ('id', ..., 'listing')
    ...
```

My URL routes are set up in the following way:

```
POST /v1/listings/:listing_id/images
```

in the view, I get the listing based on path param:

```
def upload_photo_to_listing(request, listing_id):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    data = request.data.copy()
    data['listing'] = listing

    serializer = ListingImageSerializer(
        data=data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This works fine (removed error handling for simplicity); however, I do not like mutating request.data (or copying and mutating it). When using original object, I can do something like this:

```
ListingImageSerializer(someListingImageObject, data=data, ...)
```

Is it possible to do something similar to it but instead of original objects, actually pass the related field?

Comment: you can try add listing_id inside request.data before call `def upload_photo_to_listing(request, listing_id)`. Like json request have this `{'listing': 1}`. Can you show your request ?

Comment: The request does not come with listing as it kills the purpose of listing_id in the URL. I tried to make it be restful as images are relations to listing_id. If I send listing ID via request, then the URL can become /v1/listings/images. That doesn't seem correct to me in terms of RESTfulness because I am adding images to one listing.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the listing related object id directly in the json like

```
{
     "id" : 1,
     "listing" : 1
}
```

Now in the views.py

```
def upload_photo_to_listing(request, listing_id):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    data = request.data

    serializer = ListingImageSerializer(
        data=data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
    return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Sorry, I was thinking of somehow passing the listing object to the serializer, just like how we do it for non-related own fields (sending object as first argument of serializer).